# Command not found

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to shell scripting

Below is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

first_num = 0
second_num = 0

echo -n "Enter the first number =>"
read first_num
echo -n "Enter the second number =>"
read second_num

echo "first + second = $((first_num + second_num))"
```

Whenever I run it, it prints like below

```
/Users/haani/arithmetic.bash: line 3: first_num: command not found 

/Users/haani/arithmetic.bash: line 4: second_num: command not found  

Enter the first number =>
```

What could be the reason for command not found here?

Comment: Spaces aren't allowed around the = in shell variable assignment.

Comment: Spaces. `first_num = 0` runs a command named `first_num`, passing it arguments `=` and `0`.

Comment: ...btw, `echo -n` is undefined behavior by the POSIX standard -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html -- the better option is `printf`. (On XSI systems, for instance, `echo -n` prints `-n` on its output, and POSIX explicitly allows this).

Comment: I don't know what POSIX is, however I am using echo -n for making sure that the cursor stays there in the same line to take an input from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try without spaces:

```
first_num=1
```

Comment: Answering obvious dupes? Tsk, tsk.